# In C code how to convert string to exponential value?

Tags: c

In the below code sniped the output of second print is chan 5.63e-11 ull 0.000000000000000, but i'm expecting ull value to be 0.0000000000563. Not sure what's going wrong here.
enter code here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    char *ser;
    char *res;
    char chan[10];
    int len;
    int i;
    res = "BER=5.63e-11!";

    ser = strstr(res,"BER=");

    ser = ser+4;
    len = strlen(ser);
    printf("\n ser %s len %d",ser,len);
    i=0;
    while(len-1) {
        chan[i] = ser[i];
        //printf("\n ser %c chan %s",ser[i],chan);
        len--;
        i++;
    }
    double ull;
    ull = atof(chan);
    printf("\n chan %s ull %.15f",chan,ull);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the line `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: yes. Adding headers here, #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

Comment: @SushilKumar You definitely also need `<stdlib.h>`.  You should have gotten a compiler warning like `implicit declaration of function 'atof' is invalid`.

Comment: You don't \0-terminate `chan`.

Comment: Do not show the included headers in the comments. Edit the post so it contains all the information needed for the question. A debugging question should contain a [mre]. For this question, it should contain a **complete program**, including all the `#include` directives and the definition of `main`, so that a reader can copy the source code, paste it directly into a new file, and compile it with no further edits.

Comment: Why don't you simply use ˙`ull = atof(ser);`? You do not need `chan` and `while` loop at all..

Comment: @Laci tried it, doesn't work

Comment: @PaulHankin can you help in terminating and getting the right answer, i'm not able to get right answer even after terminating

Comment: Because `5.63e-11!` is not a number, remove `!`

Comment: @Laci chan doesn't have '!', output:- chan 5.63e-11 uul 0.000000000000000

Comment: @SushilKumar: It works just fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/GMTo6G41j.

Comment: @Laci: That shouldn't be necessary, `atof` should ignore everything after the number.

Comment: @Clifford gcc 9.4 , is it complier issue

Comment: @Nate of course, you are right....

Comment: Indeed even your original (unnecessarily complicated) code works fine on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/5G7v6oxaj.  There might be something wrong with your compiler or runtime, or it has limitations you've overlooked.  Note the behavior of `atof` is defined by the C library, not the compiler, so you should state your operating system, etc.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for update, I'm new bee on C. Stack overflow is the platform were I can interact with Beautiful and Awesome coder and learn from each one of you.

Comment: @SushilKumar If you're still having issues, to eliminate all other issues, try running the minimal `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> int main() { printf("%.15f\n", atof("5.63e-11")); }`.  If that doesn't work, it proves there's something wrong with your system's version of `atof`.

Comment: [Don't use `atof()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1p1): "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."  Use [`strtod()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.3) `strtod()` doesn't invoke undefined behavior on bad input, and unlike `atof()` it can actually indicate that the input was bad.  `atof()` has no way to signal any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour so not easily reproduced.  You can force the error by initialising `chan` thus:  `char chan[10]="000000000";` then the cause becomes clear:

You do not initialise `chan` and you fail to terminate the string.  If the unitialised character at `chan[8]` happens to be a digit (because it has to be something, and can be anything), the exponent will be much larger than 11, and all significant digits displayed will be zero.  That will be why the issue could not be reproduced - the content of the unitialised array is undefined an non-deterministic.

So for example if the unitialised `chan` happened to contain:

```
{'q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','0','a','b'}
                                  ^
```

after the while loop it will be:

```
{'5','6','.','3','e','-','1','1','0','a','b'}
                          ^   ^   ^
```

So `atof()` converts `"56.3e-110"`, terminating when iot encounters the invalid `'a'`.

You can fix the issue simply by zero (NUL) initialising `chan` thus:

```
char chan[10] = {0} ;
```

and/or terminating the string after the while loop:

```
chan[i] = '\0' ;
```

However all that is entirely unnecessary given that the while loop and `chan` can be replaced with:

```
double ull = atof( ser ) ;
```

`atof()` will stop converting at the first invalid character (`'!'` in this case).

If the validity of the string is not a precondition, you can combine validation with conversion using `sscanf()` thus:

```
double ull = 0.0 ; 
int valid = sscanf( ser, "%lf", &ull ) ;
if( valid == 0 )
{ 
    // handle conversion error
}
```

Or you might use `strtod()` for which the return value on invalid input is zero.  However you cannot distinguish between invalid input and an actual zero; but if your error handling strategy is to set `ull` to 0.0 in any case that may not matter:

```
double ull = strtod( ser, NULL ) ;
```

Comment: *`atof()` will stop converting at the first invalid character...* But if the input isn't a numeric value, undefined behavior is invoked.  The only safe way to use `atof()` is to validate that its input is a numeric value that can be converted to a `double`.  And once you've done that, you've pretty much already converted it to a `double`:  "Is this a number?  Yep.  Does its value fit into a `double`?  Yep.  OK, now I can safely call `atof()`!"

Comment: @AndrewHenle All true, but the string in this case is hard coded (not input), so no validation required.  The wisdom or otherwise of using `atof()` is not really part of the question.  That said, I would suggest `double ull = 0.0 ; int valid = sscanf( ser, "%lf", &ull ) ;` where a valid number is not a pre-condition.

Comment: @AndrewHenle actually I think undefined behaviour only occurs if the numeric string represents a real number beyond the range representable by `double`.  If it is simply not a number, it returns zero.  I have added alternative conversion methods , even though it is probably beyond the scope of the question.